# append image to EXISTING pdf using itextsharp

Tags: image, itext

The following code is very good at putting a single page into a pdf.
It does not work for subsequent pages.
If the stream is an existing pdf file the image is replaced. How do I get NewPage() to actually create a new page and add the image at the end.

```
        using (Stream ms = GetStream()) {

            Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4);
            var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, ms);

            doc.Open();
            if (!doc.NewPage())
                throw new InvalidOperationException("NewPage failed.");

            PDFImage jpg = PDFImage.GetInstance(image, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            jpg.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
            jpg.ScaleToFit(PageSize.A4.Width, PageSize.A4.Height);
            doc.Add(jpg);

            doc.Close();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling `doc.NewPage()` doesn't do anything when there's nothing on the current page.  There are at least 3 options:

1) Add something invisible to the current page.  An empty paragraph, some white space to the PdfContentByte, whatever.
2) Tell your PDF document "no, its really not empty, take my word":  `PdfDocument.PageEmpty  =false;`
3) Don't throw when `NewPage` returns false. That's perfectly acceptable under the circumstances.

I'd go with #3 personally.